# Should Bower be Updating a Package Every Time Repeatedly?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

Not much to the question really - I have an error when trying to build with gulp (first highlight). I noticed when I run "bower update bootswatch," it downloads something every time. I have very little experience with package management, so I was wondering if this is a problem, and if it is, what I can do about it.

Edit: An important note is that it doesn't reinstall/re-download any of the other tens of packages.

Edit 2: On the end of the big rectangle there is a covered-up part: "invalid-meta bootswatch is missing "main" entry in bower.json" - is this important?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the history of bower questions on here, I am guessing no one has any clue as to what's going on, understandably - neither do I. With that said, I am posting a lazy "solution": After verifying versions and such are exactly the same with a co-worker, but the file content is different, my coworker sent me his bootswatch folder and I copied it into bower components. That fixed it.